# Implementing scroll bar, but cursor is not moving at all? Also, if you could please let me know how to embed mouse-scroll in this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, scrollbar

**my css code :** This is for the scrollbar view, and the movement of the bar

```
#updateHolder {      /*this describes the outer structure of the scroll bar  */
    width: 300px;  /* <= For Width: change the width value */
    color: #333;   /***/
    margin-top: 10px;    /***/
    overflow: hidden;    /***/
    border:0px solid #CCCCCC;    /***/
}

#updateContainer {                      /***/
    background-color: white;           /***/
    position: relative;                 /***/
    cursor: pointer;                   /***/    

}

#updateContent {
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    padding-right: 12px;
}

#updateScollBar {                           /***/
    background: #F2F2F2;                       /***/
    border-left: 1px solid #DADADA;              /***/
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;                             /***/
    right: 0;                              /***/
    bottom: 0;                          /***/
    cursor: default;
    zoom: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=25); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    opacity: 0.25;
}

#updateScollScrubber {
    background-color: 909090;
    width: 9px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    border-left:1px solid #676767;
    border-top:1px solid #676767;

}

#updateScollBar, #updateContainer, #updateHolder {
    height: 300px; /* <= For Height: change the height value */ }
```

**Javascript code :** Though I mentioning it differently, I have embedded it in my html code which i have pasted just below it

```
$(document).ready(function(){     //This code doesnt enable mouse-scrolling

    var _offsetY = 0,
    _startY = 0,
    scrollStep = 10,
    isScrollBarClick = false,
    contentDiv,
    scrubber,
    scrollHeight,
    contentHeight,
    scrollFaceHeight,
    initPosition,
    initContentPos,
    moveVal,
    scrubberY = 0;

    element = document.getElementById("updateHolder");
    if (element.addEventListener)
        /** DOMMouseScroll is for mozilla. */
        element.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
    /** IE/Opera. */
    element.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;

    // To resize the height of the scroll scrubber when scroll height increases.
    setScrubberHeight();

    contentDiv = document.getElementById('updateContainer');

    scrubber = $('#updateScollScrubber');

    scrollHeight = $('#updateScollBar').outerHeight();

    contentHeight = $('#updateContent').outerHeight();

    scrollFaceHeight = scrubber.outerHeight();

    initPosition = 0;            /***/

    initContentPos = $('#updateHolder').offset().top;             /***/

    // Calculate the movement ration with content height and scrollbar height
    moveVal = (contentHeight - scrollHeight)/(scrollHeight - scrollFaceHeight);

    $('#updateHolder').bind('mousewheel', wheel);

    $("#updateScollScrubber").mouseover(function() {
        // Enable Scrollbar only when the content height is greater then the view port area.
        isScrollBarClick = false;
        if(contentHeight > scrollHeight) {
            // Show scrollbar on mouse over
            $(this).animate({opacity: 1});
            scrubber.bind("mousedown", onMouseDown);
        }
    }).mouseout(function() {
        isScrollBarClick = false;
        if(contentHeight > scrollHeight) {
            // Hide Scrollbar on mouse out.
            $(this).animate({opacity: 0.25});
            $('#updateHolder').unbind("mousemove", onMouseMove);
            scrubber.unbind("mousedown", onMouseDown);
        }
    });

    $("#updateScollBar").mousedown(function(){              /***/
        isScrollBarClick = true;                           /***/
    }).mouseout(function(){
        isScrollBarClick = false;                            /***/
    }).mouseup(function(event) {
        if( isScrollBarClick == false )
             return;
        if ((event.pageY - initContentPos) > (scrollHeight - scrubber.outerHeight())) {
            scrubber.css({top: (scrollHeight - scrubber.outerHeight())});
        }else{
            scrubber.css({top: (event.pageY - initContentPos) - 5});
        }
        $('#updateContent').css({top: ((initContentPos - scrubber.offset().top) * moveVal)});
    });

    function onMouseDown(event) {
        $('#updateHolder').bind("mousemove", onMouseMove);
        $('#updateHolder').bind("mouseup", onMouseUp);
        _offsetY = scrubber.offset().top;
        _startY = event.pageY + initContentPos;
        // Disable the text selection inside the update area. Otherwise the text will be selected while dragging on the scrollbar.
        contentDiv.onselectstart = function () { return false; } // ie
        contentDiv.onmousedown = function () { return false; } // mozilla
    }

    function onMouseMove(event) {

        isScrollBarClick = false;
        // Checking the upper and bottom limit of the scroll area
        if((scrubber.offset().top >= initContentPos) && (scrubber.offset().top  (initContentPos + scrollHeight - scrollFaceHeight)) {
                scrubber.css({top: (scrollHeight-scrollFaceHeight-2)});
                $('#updateContent').css({top: (scrollHeight - contentHeight + initPosition)});
            }
            $('#updateHolder').trigger('mouseup');
        }
    }

    function onMouseUp(event) {
        $('#updateHolder').unbind("mousemove", onMouseMove);
        contentDiv.onselectstart = function () { return true; } // ie
        contentDiv.onmousedown = function () { return true; } // mozilla
    }

    function setScrubberHeight() {                         /***/
        cH = $('#updateContent').outerHeight();
        sH = $('#updateScollBar').outerHeight();
        if(cH > sH) {
            // Set the min height of the scroll scrubber to 20
            if(sH / ( cH / sH ) < 20) {              $('#updateScollScrubber').css({height: 20 });           }else{              $('#updateScollScrubber').css({height: sH / ( cH / sH ) });             }       }   }   function onMouseWheel(dir) {         scrubberY = scrubber.offset().top + (scrollStep * dir) - initContentPos;         if ((scrubberY) > (scrollHeight - scrubber.outerHeight())) {
            scrubber.css({top: (scrollHeight - scrubber.outerHeight())});
        }else {
            if(scrubberY < 0) scrubberY = 0;
            scrubber.css({top: scrubberY});
        }
        $('#updateContent').css({top: ((initContentPos - scrubber.offset().top) * moveVal)});
    }

    /** This is high-level function.
     * It must react to delta being more/less than zero.
     */
    function handle(delta) {
            if (delta < 0) {
                onMouseWheel(1);
            }
            else {
                onMouseWheel(-1);
            }
    }

    /** Event handler for mouse wheel event. /***/
     */
    function wheel(event){   /***/
            var delta = 0;    /***/
            if (!event) /* For IE. */    /***/
                    event = window.event;  /***/
            if (event.wheelDelta) { /* IE/Opera. */
                    delta = event.wheelDelta/120;
            } else if (event.detail) { /** Mozilla case. */
                    /** In Mozilla, sign of delta is different than in IE.
                     * Also, delta is multiple of 3.
                     */
                    delta = -event.detail/3;
            }
            /** If delta is nonzero, handle it.
             * Basically, delta is now positive if wheel was scrolled up,
             * and negative, if wheel was scrolled down.
             */ /***/ /***/ /***/ /***/ /***/ /***/ /***/ /***/
            if (delta)
                    handle(delta);
            /** Prevent default actions caused by mouse wheel.
             * That might be ugly, but we handle scrolls somehow
             * anyway, so don't bother here..
             */
            if (event.preventDefault)
                    event.preventDefault();
            event.returnValue = false;
    } });
```

**HTML code goes here** I am not sure but I think I am making some mistake here

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css_file.css" media="screen" />

<div id="updateHolder">
    <div id="updateContainer">
    <div id="updateContent">

//Placing my content here


     Dummy Text <img src="http://articles.tutorboy.com/wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_smile.gif" alt=":)" class="wp-smiley">
    msg
orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. 
    </div>



    <div id="updateScollBar">
        <div id="updateScollScrubber">
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Really sorry for poor html representation as I could not represent the tags properly. 
ANY HELP WOULD BE REALLY APPRECIATED. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell exactly what you are asking, but if you just want to add in a scrollbar you can put it into your div tage like this;

```
<div id="updateHolder" style="width: 300px; height: 100px; overflow: auto">
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gonzy/4S7kL/)
 is a jsfiddle with it in action

Comment: that's a default scrollbar. I wouldn't have to write such a big code if I wish for the default one ;) right?

Comment: I have tried implementing a gmail style scrollbar.. it is showing the scrollbar but not moving :(

Comment: if you're looking for easily customizable scrollbars I would suggest using jquery, is that an option?

Comment: it really depends on what styling you are looking for,
here:http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/
is a simple one you can just hit download and check it out yourself, there are tons out there

Comment: Neat.. but I am still not able to understand why the above code is not working. JS is right, still not working.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with mousewheel programming, but I think the use of delta is a bit outdated, its more common to use event.wheel > 0, here is a link with it being used http://jsfiddle.net/gonzy/zYXT5/